# How to achieve after-image pixel shader effect

Tags: xna-4.0, hlsl, fragment-shader

How would one go about writing a pixel shader like this one in XNA 4.0?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1uZvurrhig&feature=related

Comment: This wouldn't be implemented via a pure pixel-shader. The most likely method is to render the scene to a texture, increase the contrast of that image and slowly fade it out over a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the [shaders section](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=0&devarea=14&platform=0&sort=1) of Microsoft's App Hub XNA samples and start poking around.

The [bloom sample](http://create.msdn.com/education/catalog/sample/bloom) demonstrates a similar effect.

To achieve the effect from the video you would want to render the highlights to a buffer, which you then would clear gradually (using a semi-transparent quad), rather than clearing it completely each frame.

(Or you might bounce it between buffers, with a shader that does the appropriate fall-off.)

Answer (score -2):

> How would one go about writing a pixel shader like this one in XNA
>   4.0?

1. learn how pixel shaders work by researching websites, articles, books.
2. follow various tutorials and gain familiarity and comfort level with
   HLSL.
3. experiment. experiment. Ask ***specific questions*** about it. Play around till you get it.